# Rails, Devise, Sign up = write name in other Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I use Rails 4 and Devise. I set it up that the user needs to register and sign in with a username instead of a email. Now, as soon as a User signs up I want to write a name in another db which is called Room. So I got the users_controller with the following:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' 
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end       
end
```

Basically what I want now is that the username which the user enters will be used to create a Room, I want that to happen in there but don't know really how I should realize that:

```
@room = Room.new(???)
```

??? should be the username of the User registration process. How do I integrate something like that in the Devise registration process?

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If users has one Room, consider using an `after_create` callback in the `user.rb` model. In that callback create a `Room`.

```
self.create_room(name: self.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There will only be one room per person. I tried around with after_create but I always get an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `rooms' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection). :(

Comment: If a User has_one Room, the above code will work in the after_create callback. In the future when posting a Rails question including the Model(s) code will help produce better answers.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for providing not enough info, I am pretty new to Rails. I got it working now, thanks! But rooms.create would only be for has_many for has_one (which was my case) it would be create_room.